# Requisição Cors para webservice

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando submeter um formulário via POST para um `WebService` porém estou tendo o seguinte problema:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Já adicionei filtros de CORS ao projeto com os `WebServices`.

Essa é a minha requisição:

```
$("#frmLogin").submit(function(e){
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var fUrl = $(this).attr("action");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: fUrl,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        xhrFields:{
            withCredentials: false
        },
        crossDomain : true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
        },
        data: postData,
        success: function(result){
            alert('sucesso');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('erro');
        }

    });
});
```

Falta algo nela?

Comment: Estás a submeter para o mesmo domínio ou outro? no segundo caso tens a certeza que o serviço aceita `POST`s externos?

Comment: a requisição está sendo feita de um domínio diferente. No caso do serviço eu configurei desta forma: adicionei algumas configurações ao arquivo web.xml

Comment: A saber: <filter>
  <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
   <param-value>*</param-value>... etc

Answer (score 2):

No seu $.ajax adicione a opção

```
headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
```

Comment: Vou tentar desta forma. Obrigado.

Comment: Também é possível adicionar para qual domínio específico deseja liberar.